# Qt, Editing widget outside of constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I have:

```
Game::Game ( QWidget * parent ) :
        QWidget ( parent ), ui ( new Ui::Game )
{  
    ui->setupUi ( this ) ;
    ui->progressBar_Loading->setValue ( 0 ) ;
}
```

I can't call `ui->progressBar_Loading->setValue ( 25 ) ;` in a static function so I tried:

```
QProgressBar * progressBar_Loading;

Game::Game ( QWidget * parent ) :
        QWidget ( parent ), ui ( new Ui::Game )
{
    progressBar_Loading = ui->progressBar_Loading;
}
```

But this causes the app to crash upon startup. Any known solutions?

Comment: Of-course you can call it anywhere in the class `Game`. That's because `ui` is a class member. What do you mean by "an issue with the way that Qt is designed" ?

Comment: Looks like you are missing some basic OOP concepts. Anyway, `Game::Game` looks like a constructor, not a static method. Also, you are initializing `ui`, which gives you a valid member `ui` that you can reference at your constructor body (if `Game::Game` really is a constructor). Post more code so we can help you more.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira am not missing any basic oop concepts I just worded my question wrong; the constructor and the function that I am trying to call are two different things

Answer (score 0):

you can call the `ui->progressBar_Loading->setValue ( 25 ) ;` anywhere inside the class  outside the constructor  if the ui is not declared as a local variable for constructor, I will provide an example which is working for me,
widget.h class definition

```
namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QTimer *timer;

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

public slots:
    void updateProgressBar();
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QDebug>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
    timer = new QTimer;
    timer->start(500);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(updateProgressBar()));
    show();
}

void Widget::updateProgressBar()
{
    int k = ui->progressBar->value();
    qDebug() << "Updating" << k ;
    ui->progressBar->setValue(++k);
    timer->start(500);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Just create an Object for widget , it will work,

Comment: my function is static so when I try to do this I get `error: invalid use of member 'Game::ui' in static member function`; if i make the Ui::Game variable static it gives me further issues.

Answer (score 0):

> Static member functions are really global functions, just inside the
>   class's namespace. That is, they don't have a 'this' pointer and
>   therefore can't access any other members of the class (except for
>   other static members).